# How much water should I let my dog drink?

Tags: dogs, health

My dog is a Labrador schnoodle cross and he is almost one year old. I want to know how much water I should allow him to drink because I don't want him to have too much in case its bad for him and gets kidney problems or something like that.

Comment: you need to have clean and fresh water at all times so your dog can drink when it is thirsty,failing to do this will cause kidney stones and the kidneys can potentially fail causing your dog to die.

Comment: I am not a vet or zoologist or physician, but I believe that animal's kidneys work all the same way. The more fluid to work with the better.

Comment: Only humans need to drink when they're not thirsty so that they keep buying the water.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As much as he wants! There are very few instances where you should limit the amount your dog drinks. An example would be:

- Your dog is vomiting - better to offer small amounts of water several times a day instead of him engulfing large quantities at once. If vomiting persists your pet should be seen by a veterinarian as frequent vomiting can lead to dehydration.

It is important to monitor how much he drinks as an increase can be an [indicator to illnesses](https://www.petmd.com/dog/conditions/urinary/c_multi_polydipsia_polyuria?page=show) such as diabetes and kidney disease.

Comment: What do you do if your dog is stupid and just pees all over if you give her unlimited water?

Comment: @AzorAhai there are a few questions asked on peeing in the house. If he's an older dog who just recently started this behavior : https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/15348/my-dog-is-peeing-everywhere

Comment: Another on crate training a puppy: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1793/crate-training-our-puppy-is-not-working-help?rq=1